# Copying existing posts after new post type has been added

Tags: custom-post-types

I have some existing posts of some existing type. I have created a new custom post type (with CPT UI). I now want to move these existing posts under the newly-created post type. Is this possible, or do I have to manually copy the content from these posts to have them in the new format?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to make another copy of the posts or move the old posts to new CPT? If you want to move, then there is very handy plugin called post type switcher, using it you can easily modify post type of any post and it will automatically be part of new CPT. This is the plugin I mentioned https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/

Comment: Yes, I did want to move them. Thanks for the plugin recommendation - seems to be what I was looking for, so will give it a go.

Comment: Great, i have added it as answer so it is marked as resolved. And also helps future searchers. You may mark the Answer as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want move the old posts to new CPT? If you want to move,  there is very handy plugin called post type switcher, using it you can easily modify post type of any post and it will automatically be part of new CPT.

This is the plugin I mentioned:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/